# How to add a public directory in vitejs configuration file

Tags: javascript, building, vite

I have a folder (named `assets`) with pictures, pdf files and 3d models that I want to include in the public static path at `dist` directory after building with Vite.js.

I am using this code for the `vite.config.js`:

```
  export default {
    publicDir: './assets'
  }
```

However after building, the files are not copied to the `dist` folder. When I run `vite serve` the website works, but I get "not found error" for all the files that should've been in that public folder.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Is it working for default directory `<root>/public` ?

Comment: I actually managed to solve it with this code: ```module.exports = {
    root: './',
    build: {
      outDir: 'dist',
    },
    publicDir: 'assets'
  }
  ```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not sure why, but the problem was solved with this code at `vite.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    root: './',
    build: {
        outDir: 'dist',
    },
    publicDir: 'assets'
 }
```

Comment: typo in your first vite.config.js: pulicDir

Answer (score -1):

Just adding to this one because I was stuck on it with react:

The Vite config docs specify this format:

```
export default {
  // config options
}
```

They also suggest you pop this tag on the top for auto completion:

```
/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
export default defineConfig({
  // config options
})
```

When I added the tag it auto completed the build directory config for me:

```
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        outDir: 'public',
    },
})
```