# How to find image assets in production build

Tags: javascript, vite

My project uses a selection of `.svg` files, chosen at random from a folder `src/assets/svg`. The following code loads the filenames into an array so that individual images can be chosen later:

```
const svgImages = [''];

function setupLibrary() {

    let modules;

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
        modules = import.meta.glob('/src/assets/svg/*.svg');
    else
        modules = import.meta.glob('/assets/*.svg');

    for (const path in modules) {
        svgImages.push(path);
    }
}
```

This works fine in dev mode, but in production no files are found (`modules` is empty). The build process adds all the `.svg` files to the assets folder along with the `.js` and `.css` files.

I have also tried `modules = import.meta.glob('/*.svg')` and simlar without success.

I have also looked at similar questions and answers, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180561/vite-change-ouput-directory-of-assets), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68654761/how-to-add-a-public-directory-in-vitejs-configuration-file) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68547439/assets-not-showing-after-build-process-with-vite-and-vue3) but without success. I have also read [the vite docs](https://v2.vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html) but cannot find a solution.

vite.config.ts:

```
// Plugins
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

// Utilities
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({ 
      template: { transformAssetUrls }
    }),
    // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
    }),
  ],
  define: { 'process.env': {} },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.jsx',
      '.mjs',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx',
      '.vue'
    ],
  },
  server: {
    port: 5173,
  },
 
})
```

Comment: whats your prod file structure, the `svg` sub folder is still there, right?

Comment: no, the \dist folder has only an assets folder, no other subfolders. I have now added the vite config file if that helps

Comment: did you `console.log(path)` in modules?

Comment: What do you mean exactly here? I have tried to find the current path in production mode, so that I can use that in `import.meta.glob` - but have failed. Tried the second answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243 but get error `fileURLToPath` not exported.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `{ eager: true }` like this

```
const svgImages = [];

function setupLibrary() {
    const modules =  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'?
        import.meta.glob('/src/assets/svg/*.svg', { eager: false }):
        import.meta.glob('/assets/*.svg', { eager: true });

    for (const path in modules) {
        svgImages.push(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, tried somehing similar from another post. Tried it again now, but no success. BTW you cannot use variables in `glob` (only literal paths)  so I had to re-arrange your code back to more like my original.

Comment: Oh OK. I will change code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my approach and solved it as below. It has required renaming all (44) `.svg` files as `svg1.svg`, `svg2.svg` etc, which is tedious (but took me only 10 minutes, not 10 hours I tried with other methods!)

```
let svgImages = [] as string[];

function setupLibrary() {
    for (let file=1; file < 100; file++) {
        try {
            const img =   new URL(`/src/assets/svg/svg${file}.svg`, import.meta.url).href;
            if (img.includes('undefined') === false)
                svgImages.push(img);
            else    
                break;
        }
        catch(e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log('images: ' + svgImages);
}
```

This works both from the local `dist` folder (using `npm run build` then `npm run preview`), and also on the production server.

If there was an easy way of finding the number of files in that folder, or better still to get an array listing their names, the method would be much improved.